# BeautifulSoup returns empty list when parsed for links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am new to web scraping and I am trying to extract links and table data from a website using BeautifulSoup. However, it returns none even though there are links in the webpage. I can find the links by inspecting the webpage in the browser.

Here is the code I am using

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "http://www.ms2soft.com/tcds/?loc=Txdot&mod=tcds&local_id=57CC441"
driver.get(url)

content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
pageData = soup(content, "html.parser")
links = pageData.find_all('a')
```

The webpage gives the traffic data of the Dallas city. I have used `requests`and `urllib` modules as well without luck.

Comment: which links as there's many links, and which tables as there's many also !

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Any table in the webpage. For example, table with id ```tblTable1```. I cannot parse any table data or link data on the web page. A bit of digging taught me that web page has Java script, which is not straight forward to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this particular service does not make any direct requests to an API - this would be very convenient since it means you can simply imitate a request to the same API and (most likely) get back easy-to-parse JSON.

This page happens to use ajax and serves .asp files - that means the server executes some script(s) with which to generate the actual HTML, which it then serves to you. It also happens to serve different .asp files for each different table - basically I'm saying this isn't that fun to scrape. You'll probably have to write slightly different solutions for each of the different tables to get the content you want.

Here's kind of a base project I came up with. You create a `requests.Session` to keep track of cookies (the server happens to care about session cookies in this case). Then you make the actual requests to the .asp resources for each table you want to scrape (in my example I'm just scraping the AADT (Annual Average Daily Traffic) table) - each table has a unique URL, which you can find by looking at your browser's network/resource/traffic logger. Looking at the Query-String / Requests Parameters in Google Chrome's Developer tools I picked some parameters that seemed like they would be important for the particular record you want to scrape. I then came up with a gross list-comprehension to make the scraped data somewhat more presentable - this is the part which will probably be different for every table.

```
def main():

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from itertools import groupby

    session_url = "https://txdot.ms2soft.com/tcds/tsearch.asp"

    session = requests.Session()
    session_response = session.get(session_url)
    session_response.raise_for_status()

    aadt_url = "https://txdot.ms2soft.com/tcds/ajax/tcds_tdetail_aadt.asp"

    params = {
        "offset": "0",
        "agency_id": "97",
        "local_id": "57CC441"
    }

    aadt_response = session.get(aadt_url, params=params)
    aadt_response.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(aadt_response.content, "html.parser")

    rows = list(list(group) for key, group in groupby([item.find(text=True, recursive=False) for item in soup.find_all("td", {"class": "FormRow"})], key=lambda i: i and i.isprintable()) if key)
    print(rows)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
[['2018', '1,482'], ['2017', '1,482', '246', '17'], ['2016', '1,488', '255', '17', '100'], ['2015', '1,199', '155', '13']]
>>>
```